# Tailwind @apply not working when I run "npm run start"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering

I'm using Nuxt 2 and I've created the file ~/assets/css/main.sass. When i run **npm run dev** everithing works well (see the button in first image), but if I run **npm run build** and then **npm run start**, the Tailwind classes don't get applied to the button.

**NPM RUN DEV**
[image: Tailwind classes applied to the button]

**NPM RUN START**
[image: Tailwind classes not applied]

I tried many different settings, no success.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me or not, i just installed **sass** package and now it works.

Comment: I guess your existing project didn't just "know" it had to compile sass files into css. Installing tailwind doesn't mean it adds the necessary package to the existing project.